Error SMS text response following nextKeyword
We are encountering an error in the SMS. Hope to find some help here.
We have 12 SMSs in different journeys. We use text responses to capture the replies and we push a next keyword to move to the next message. The SMS use the same AMPscript, yet 3 of them show an error. Here’s the process:
A first SMS is sent with a question. There’s a next keyword and the next SMS replies with a number. However, when we reply, we receive this error:
"there was an error processing your message"
Question : Do you think we have a typo in the code, or is it related to a mobile process we're not aware of?
Thanks a lot for your help

Here is the AMP script for the errored message:
%%[

var @response, @isValid, @errorMessage, @message

set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if trim(RegExMatch(trim(concat(" ", @response)), '([0-9]+)', 1)) != "" and @response >= 0 and @response <= 10 then

    set @isValid = "true"

else

    set @isValid = "false"

    set @errorMessage = "Invalid response. Please reply with a number between 0 and 10."

ENDIF

if @isValid == "true" then

    UpsertData('NAMEOFDE',1,'Phone',MOBILE_NUMBER,'ResponseDay7-2', @response)

    set @message = 'Thanks, here's to itch improvement!'

ELSE

    set @message = @errorMessage

UpsertData('NAMEOFDE',1,'Phone',MOBILE_NUMBER,'ResponseDay7-2', @response)

CreateSMSConversation('000000',MOBILE_NUMBER,'RESPONSEDAY72','MOBILECONNECT')

endif

]%%

%%=v(@message)=%%



From my experience, the error SMS response "There was an error processing your message." shows up when there is an error in the AMPscript block, making MC cannot render the message correctly for the send.
The 's in the 23rd line
set @message = 'Thanks, here's to itch improvement!' needs to be escaped and the check condition in the line 7th should be improved.
I don't test it yet but you can try this version to see if it works
%%[

var @response, @isValid, @errorMessage, @message

set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if trim(RegExMatch(trim(concat(" ", @response)), '([0-9]+)', 1)) != "" and Length(@response) > 0 and Length(@response) <= 10 then

    set @isValid = "true"

else

    set @isValid = "false"

    set @errorMessage = "Invalid response. Please reply with a number between 0 and 10."

ENDIF

if @isValid == "true" then

    UpsertData('NAMEOFDE',1,'Phone',MOBILE_NUMBER,'ResponseDay7-2', @response)

    set @message = "Thanks, here's to itch improvement!"

ELSE

    set @message = @errorMessage

UpsertData('NAMEOFDE',1,'Phone',MOBILE_NUMBER,'ResponseDay7-2', @response)

CreateSMSConversation('000000',MOBILE_NUMBER,'RESPONSEDAY72','MOBILECONNECT')

endif

]%%

%%=v(@message)=%%



Hello Duc Le, it helps! Thanks for your support :)
